# JMeter: Updating JSON array using Groovy

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I want to fetch a Non-Zero Account Number from Accounts array from below JSON. I am able to Fetch the Accounts in a variable.

```
    {
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "**Acronym**": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "Accounts": [{"Number":"0","Name":"Zero"},{"Number":"123","Name":"OneTwo"}]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am lost on how to find "Number":"123", and Update the "Name":"OneTwo" to "Name":"OneTwoThree" using Groovy in JMeter. What do I use in this case, what would be efficient, as I will have to run this for several hundred users? Any hints?

```
[{"Number":"0","Name":"Zero"},{"Number":"123","Name":"OneTwo"}]
```

Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def builder = new JsonBuilder(response)

response.glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.Accounts.findAll { account -> account.Number.equals('123') }.each { account -> account.Name = 'OneTwoThree' }

def data = builder.toPrettyString()
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)